# Show that an elastic jump is in $H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, lebesgue-integral

I want to prove the following statement:

Let $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\bar{\Gamma})$, 
$\nabla u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\bar{\Gamma})$.

Define
$[u]=\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}u(x+hn(x))-u(x-hn(x))$, where $n(x)$ is the unit vector normal to $\Gamma$ at $x$.

Then $[u]\in H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$.

I am using the definition $$H^{1/2}(\Gamma)=\left\{u\in L^2(\Gamma)\,:\,\int_\Gamma(1+|y|^2)^{1/2}|\hat{u}(y)|^2dy<\infty\right\}.$$

where 
$$\hat{u}(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}[u](x)e^{-2\pi ixy}dy$$
is the Fourier Transform of $u$.

Essentially I want to show that

$$\int_{\Gamma}(1+|y|^2)^{1/2}\int_\Gamma \left(\lim_{h\to 0^+}u(x+hn(x))-u(x-hn(x))\right)e^{-2\pi i x y}dxdy<\infty.$$

The reason that the inner integral is over $\Gamma$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^n$ because $[u]$ is zero wherever $\nabla u$ is defined and by assumption $\nabla u$ is defined almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{\Gamma}$

I am stuck because I don't know how to rewrite $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}u(x+hn(x))-u(x-hn(x))$$ which uses the fact that $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{\Gamma})$, 
$\nabla u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\bar{\Gamma})$.

One way that I could introduce $\nabla u$ is with the mean value theorem:
$$u(x+hn(x))-u(x-hn(x))=2h\nabla u(x+h\theta(h)n(x))\cdot n(x),$$ where $\theta(h)\in [-1,1]$.

But $u$ is not differentiable in $\Gamma$, so the gradient is not defined at $h=0$ and for the mean value theorem I need the gradient to exist for $\forall h\in [-1,1]$.

It would be especially nice if you could give me some general tips about proofs involving the function $[u]$ (for example some nice properties of $[u]$)

Thanks, Andrew Murdza